# How to compress last modified file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compression, last-modified

I have lots of file which have same name in a directory. I want to compress (zip, etc) the last modified file in MyDirectory. Can you help me please?

I can compress a file but not last modified file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream sourceFile = File.OpenRead(@"C:\MyDirectory");
    FileStream destFile = File.Create(@"C:\MyDirectory.zip");
    GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(destFile, CompressionMode.Compress);
    try
    {
        int theByte = sourceFile.ReadByte();
        while (theByte != -1)
        {
            compStream.WriteByte((byte)theByte);
            theByte = sourceFile.ReadByte();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        compStream.Dispose();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("file is compressed successfully");
}
```

Comment: If you have .NET 4.5 you could use the `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` class.

Comment: What operating system are you running?  Last I checked Windows required unique file-names within a given directory.  Note: `new FileInfo("foo.txt").LastWriteTime` will get you the last modified time.

Comment: If you are on 4.5 there is a nice library you can use for the compression part: [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: .NET 4.5 i have. i can compress with above codes.But i don't know get latest modified file and compress it.MyDirectory is a sample name.its real name luigiFiles. it is not so important i think

Comment: I'm surprised no one has asked how you have more than one file with the same name in the same directory?

Comment: the system gives them same name automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get last modified file:

```
string lastModified = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                               .OrderBy(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f))
                               .Last();
```

Comment: and how can i use lastmodified to compress it?

Comment: `lastModified` will contain the name of the file most recently modified - you can then open the file and compress the contents.

Comment: @user2777109: this is a file path. You can use your own code above: read file content, write it back as compressed.